# loop through a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array with this structure :

```
array('123455'=>'kjqs dkjq sdkj ','135468'=>'msldmsdlv sdml,sdmlcsdc ','16554d'=>'msljkfhsdlkjfhsmdlkfh')
```

I would like to loop through it without exceeding the limits , and how can I get the index and value

thanks

Comment: `for(i in variable)` being `variable` your array and `i` the key of the array.

Comment: You mean you have a PHP array - what you are showing is not javascript

Comment: @mplungjan I did not noticed it when I commented... Nicely spotted!

Comment: That's not an array, and it's not Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Emmerman but don't forget the `var` keyword to avoid creating global variables!
And add the check for own property to omit properties from prototypes.

```
var array = {
  '123455': 'kjqs dkjq sdkj ',
  '135468': 'msldmsdlv sdml,sdmlcsdc ',
  '16554d': 'msljkfhsdlkjfhsmdlkfh'
};

for (var key in array) {
  if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, array[key]);
  }
}
```

Besides this I think you're in the wrong language. I think it's done like this in php:

```
$array = array(
  '123455' => 'kjqs dkjq sdkj ',
  '135468' => 'msldmsdlv sdml,sdmlcsdc ',
  '16554d' => 'msljkfhsdlkjfhsmdlkfh'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo "\$array[$key] => $value.\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, missing `var` was my fault. But `hasOwnProperty` is unnecessary with simple objects.

Comment: I know it is in this case, but it can be necessary under certain conditions. So I added an explanation.

Comment: @user422039 why? It is a sparse array. What would you suggest? @Jan: console.log is firebug speak.

Comment: @user422039 Read my answer again, this is **not** an `Array`!

Answer (score -1):

```
for (key in array) {
  console.log(key+' - '+array[key]);
}
```

Comment: You shoud add a check for hasOwnProperty as well

Comment: You should always have a check like this in a for-in. What if someone extended object: `Object.prototype.somefn = function(){};`. Adding the `if` check causes no harm, protects you from the senseless bufoonery of others, and is also a JSLint recommendation.